# unset JSON object array at a particular time in php

Tags: php, json, unset

I have a php code as shown below in which I want to unset JSON object array only once in a month in php.

**php code:**

`if((date('j') == 1) && (date('H:i:s')=="12:00:00"))  {unset($whatever_you_want_to_unset);}`

The above php code is inside the file abc.php

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if there is any way I can run the code even without on page load.

The reason why I am saying "without on page load" because I might not open the page on 1st every month at 12:00:00

Comment: You can use CRON for this. Read more there -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: Is there way I can do this without cron job ?

Comment: Online CRON service? Like this one -> https://www.easycron.com/